# linux java -version only works for root user

Tags: linux-mint, java, path, jdk

I have downloaded and installed `jdk1.8.0_151` from oracle website. I defined `JAVA`_HOME and added it to the `PATH` variable in my `/etc/environment`.

Problem is when I type `java -version` command from terminal, it gives me error below :

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
* default-jre
* gcj-5-jre-headless
* openjdk-8-jre-headless
* gcj-4.8-jre-headless
* gcj-4.9-jre-headless
* openjdk-9-jre-headless
```

Try: `sudo apt install <selected package>`
However if I am root in terminal, I mean  after `sudo su`,  `java -version` works correctly. Is it normal or I am missing something? My `/etc/environment` file is as below:

```
 PATH="/home/aliinsan/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:/home/aliinsan/apache-maven-
 3.5.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/home/aliinsan/jdk1.8.0_151"
```

Thanks in advance,,

EDIT : path for my non-root user is as below:

```
aliinsan@aliinsan-Inspiron-7548 ~ $ echo $PATH
/home/aliinsan/bin:/home/aliinsan/.local/bin:/home/aliinsan/apache-
maven-
3.5.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:
/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: Do you have that `PATH` set for your non-root user?  Please add the output of `echo $PATH` from your non-root user.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Note that the multi-post on Stack Overflow at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638435/ is in the process of being closed in favour of this here.

Comment: Congratulations, you goofed up editing your shell startup files.

Comment: I have deleted other question

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams :) what should I do now?

Comment: ... Edit the correct files.

Comment: What's output of `type -a java`after you run `sudo su` ? Then you will know the valid path which doesn't appear at normal user path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems somewhat odd to install a package that you expect to be used system-wide under `/home`.  If this is something for only user `aliinsan` then, assuming that that user is using `bash` as their shell, I'd edit `~aliinsan/.bash_profile` and add:

```
export PATH="/home/aliinsan/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:${PATH}"
```

You can the `source ~/.bash_profile` in an existing shell to incorporate that change into your shell's existing environment.

If you're using a different shell, the process will be similar, but the file will be different.

If you want this version of Java available system-wide, I'd consider installing it in a different location (`/opt` for example).